# Trigger SQL Server, actualizar fecha al modificar un campo dentro de misma tabla

Tags: sql-server, trigger

Colegas, tengo el siguiente problema:
cree un trigger que al dejar una compañia fuera de servicio, me deja la hora y fecha en la cual lo desactive, el tema es que me actualiza la fecha en todas las compañias que ya estan fuera de servicio.

el trigger es:

```
create trigger AU_fue_servicio
on compania AFTER UPDATE
AS
set nocount on
update compania set fecha_fue_servicio = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
WHERE fuera_service IN (SELECT DISTINCT '+' FROM Inserted)
```

La estructura de la Tabla es:

[image: LA Tabla es:]

Los datos de la tabla son:
[image: los datos de la tabla son:]

el campo "fuera_service" tiene como dato "+" cuando esta fuera de servicio, y "-" cuando esta disponile.

Les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Pues... Tu WHERE es bastante claro. Le estás diciendo a SQLServer "Actualiza la `fecha_fue_servicio` a las `compania` cuyo `fuera_service` esté en `'+'`". Cuando haces "`Select distinct '+' from inserted`", LITERALMENTE está devolviendo el signo +. todas tus compañías fuera de servicio tienen el signo '+'. Entonces, se hace un update a todas esas compañías. Yo intentaría "`Where cod_compania in (select cod_compania from Inserted where fuera_service ='+')`

Comment: En desacuerdo con @Arriel en la solución pero de acuerdo en el problema. Tu condición WHERE es clarísima en lo que hace y coincide con lo que dices que hace. Deberías añadir una condición al WHERE ... AND cod_compania = el cod_compania modificado en la tabla compania... o de alguna forma, entregarle al UPDATE ese id.

Comment: @Arriel me sirvio tu WHERE, muy agradecido. Ahora da la fecha de actualizacion por su hora y fecha correspondiente sin alterar otras columnas.

Comment: @Alfabravo. Estoy de acuerdo con tu solución. Para este caso específico, el IN no es necesario, puesto que sólo se está trabajando con una compañía. Esteban, yo seguiría el consejo de Alfabravo. No utilices mi código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma te puede funcionar, ya que se actualiza la entidad haciendo el inner join entre la entidad y el registro que acabas de modificar cuando el valor de fuera _service sea igual a "+" y el campo que estas modificando sea fuera_service.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TrgTblCompania]
   ON  [dbo].[TblCompania] 
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(fuera_service) 
    BEGIN
        update a set fecha_fue_servicio = getdate() 
        from TblCompania a
        inner join inserted i on a.Idcompania=i.Idcompania
        where i.fuera_service = '+'
    END

END
GO
```

[image: Trigger]

Comment: Funciono perfecto!! gracias a ambos.